# How I can load HTTP resource with R?

Tags: r

Good morning, I've tried to parse the webpage with the code below, but the last line turned out an output of

> failed to load HTTP resource

Can anyone tell me how to deal with it? Thanks! The code is:

```
url3<- "http://www.atb.com.tn/devise" 
getdata3<- readHTMLTable(url3, stringAsFactor = FALSE, isURL = TRUE)
```

Comment: it working correctly in my browser

Comment: more than likely, it is a connectivity issue. I would recommend checking the url, the host server, and your own separate connection to the page

Answer (score 1):

No need for Selenium. Just dig a bit in the browser developer tools. It loads a resource `/devise` dynamically. That's the data table. The site also tries to use the browser user agent string to prevent scraping (though scraping is not a violation of their terms of use) and session cookies to ensure you hit some other page first. You can get the data with `rvest`:

```
library(rvest)

sess <- html_session("http://www.atb.com.tn/", 
                      user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.39 Safari/537.36"))
pg <- jump_to(sess, "http://www.atb.com.tn/devise")

dat <- content(pg$response, as="parsed")

html_table(html_nodes(dat, "table")[[2]], header=TRUE)

##    Monnaies                   NA Sigle Unité  Achat  Vente
## 1        NA      DOLLAR CANADIEN   CAD     1  1.438  1.459
## 2        NA     COURONNE DANOISE   DKK   100 29.625 30.072
## 3        NA         YEN JAPONAIS   JPY  1000 16.910 17.165
## 4        NA      DINAR KOWEITIEN   KWD     1  6.569  6.668
## 5        NA COURONNE NORVEGIENNE   NOK   100 23.201 23.551
## 6        NA        RYAL DE QATAR   QAR    10  5.424  5.505
## 7        NA        RYAL SAOUDIEN   SAR    10  5.266  5.345
## 8        NA    COURONNE SUEDOISE   SEK    10  2.350  2.386
## 9        NA         FRANC SUISSE   CHF    10 19.858 20.158
## 10       NA       DIRHAM DES EAU   AED    10  5.377  5.458
## 11       NA       LIVRE STERLING   GBP     1  2.871  2.914
## 12       NA       DOLLAR DES USA   USD     1  1.974  2.004
## 13       NA                 EURO   EUR     1  2.211  2.245
## 14       NA       DINAR BAHREINI   BHD     1  5.237  5.316
## 15       NA         DINAR LIBYEN   LYD     1  1.424  1.445
```

Comment: thank you so much "hrbrmstr",but he can't accept the function user_agent. Can you help me please ?

Comment: Make sure you have updated `rvest` and have `httr` installed (though it's a requirement for `rvest` so I'm really not sure what problem you are having)

Comment: I tried again and it works but in the third command line it shows me this error: No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.                                                                                                and when I spent the last command he said index out of range